# Socket.BeginReceive callback - message separator

Tags: .net, sockets

When the callback assigned by Socket.BeginReceive() gets some bytes, what is the best way to know I have the whole message? Should I have the first 4 bytes of each message I send hold the length of the message?

I am sending an XML file in each message so there is no unique character I can use as a message separator.

Comment: Yes, sending the length first is the simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a header containing two integers (4 bytes each). The first one would indicate protocol version and the second one would indicate message length. The good thing with using a header length instead of a delimiter is that you can allocate a buffer for the entire message before you start parsing it.

Using a version integer as the first header let's you change the rest of the headers, and the body, in any newer version of the protocol.

**Update in reply to the comment**

There is a difference between version number in the header and the one in the actual message. The message version is for the document, but the header version is for the protocol itself. By using a protocol version you could switch message transport from XML to Protobuf or something else for the message. You could also add a header identifying the target of the actual message.

Comment: Really good suggestion on the version number. However, we have that in our message (attribute of the root node) so we don't need it. But if we didn't, then that would be a good way to handle it. Thank you.

Comment: Good point. Our use is for a one-time event but it can't hurt even for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the specification for the protocol you are using. If it's an original protocol, write a specification. It's a bit of extra work, but it's well worth it.

In that specification, you can specify a message length. You can also prohibit a particular byte (you could user zero) in the payload and use that as a message separator. Since you're using XML, you could simply define a tag that indicates a message -- the close of that tag would indicate a complete message.

It's up to you. But spend the time to specify your protocol in detail. I promise you it will pay off.

Comment: I don't think a zero would work because XML can have a CDATA[[]] with a zero in it. I thought of a tag but then I need to parse the XML to find the end and that would be computationally expensive.

Comment: You don't need to parse the XML anyway?

Comment: I need to parse the XML once it's complete. But if that arrives in 6 blocks, I'd prefer to just parse it when I get the 6th and final block.

Comment: That seems very inefficient. If you have to do it that way, you have to. But the normal way would be to hand it to the parser as you get it and have the parser tell you if it received a complete unit.